# Can I be charge with burglary of habitation for giving someone a ride?

Tags: texas, burglary

I recently gave smy friend a ride to his uncles house and he ended up stealing. They trying to charge me for it because my friend is saying I helped him but I only gave him a ride.I live in Texas.

Comment: You need an actual lawyer.  This site does not provide personalized legal advice, and it would be unwise to rely on random internet advice when actual criminal charges are at stake.

Comment: No one "tries to charge you" for something.  They either do or do not.

Comment: @TigerGuy I suppose an exceptionally incompetent cop could try and fail to charge a suspect by misfiling the relevant paperwork, but the bar to charges is sufficiently low so that we can assume that the police tried to press charges against OP and were successful.  OP is charged with a serious crime.

Comment: Is this a real question or satire on the recent Texas abortion law?

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on whether you knew (or should have known) beforehand that your friend was going to commit a crime.

But more importantly, if you think you are likely to be charged with a crime (rightly or wrongly), **you really should get legal advice**, not opinions from the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

You "can" be charged as an accessory before the fact, if the evidence shows that you know of the intention to break into the house. This is covered in [Texas Penal Code Ch. 7](https://statutes.capitol.texas.gov/Docs/PE/htm/PE.7.htm). Driving the getaway car is also a crime, so it really depends on what you knew. See especially §7.02:

(a)  A person is criminally responsible for an offense committed by the conduct of another if:

> (1)  acting with the kind of culpability required for the offense, he
> causes or aids an innocent or nonresponsible person to engage in
> conduct prohibited by the definition of the offense;
>
> (2)  acting with intent to promote or assist the commission of the
> offense, he solicits, encourages, directs, aids, or attempts to aid
> the other person to commit the offense;  or
>
> (3)  having a legal duty to prevent commission of the offense and
> acting with intent to promote or assist its commission, he fails to
> make a reasonable effort to prevent commission of the offense.
>
> (b)  If, in the attempt to carry out a conspiracy to commit one
> felony, another felony is committed by one of the conspirators, all
> conspirators are guilty of the felony actually committed, though
> having no intent to commit it, if the offense was committed in
> furtherance of the unlawful purpose and was one that should have been
> anticipated as a result of the carrying out of the conspiracy.